# How do I delete all characters after the first space in a cell?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a list of city names followed by the state in which they are located all in one column in Excel.  How can I delete everything after the first space so that the city name is the only thing that's left in the cell?

example: A1 = "johnson TX"
should be just A1= "johnson"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you want a VBA solution since you tagged your question [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba).

This works:

```
Sub KeepCity()
    Dim strCityAndState As String
    Dim strCityOnly As String
    strCityAndState = Range("A1").Value
    strCityOnly = Left(strCityAndState, InStr(strCityAndState, " ") - 1)
    Range("A2").Value = strCityOnly
End Sub
```

If you don't want VBA and want a cell formula instead, then [@JToland's answer works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5833188/119775), though this one is more concise and doesn't keep the trailing space character:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Well doing something like this

```
=Mid(A1, 1, Find(" ",A1))
```

in another column should grab all text *before* the " ". So you could build another column with just all the city names and then you could use that column for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a VBA function, you can use `Left` and `InStr` as shown below.

```vb
Dim Temp As String: Temp = "Hello_World! This is my first answer here. :D"
Temp = Left(Temp, InStr(Temp, " ")-1)
```

In which case, `Temp` will be `"Hello_World!"`

Answer (score 1):

**Use of `Split` function**

An elegant approach is to use the first token of the `Split` function:

**Code Example extracting from cell A1 to A2**

```
Option Explicit

Sub KeepCity()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")   ' << Change to your sheet name
    ws.[A2] = Split(ws.[A1], " ")(0)
End Sub
```

**Alternative Syntax**

Instead of cell abbreviations `[A2]` or `[A1]` you can also use:

```
ws.Range("A2").Value = Split(ws.Range("A1").Value, " ")(0)
```

**Note**

The resulting split 1-dimensional array is zero based, so you get the first part (or token) of the original string via index `(0)`.

If you are looking for a second part, I recommend adding an additional delimiter value (" ") to the original string, e.g. `s`: `MsgBox split(s & " "," ")(1)`. By that way you avoid error number 9 `"Subscript out of range"`, if there is no delimiter in between at all, thus no second part at all.