# Delete all characters after the first space in a cell all through out the column

Tags: vba, excel

As a follow up from the question below:

[How do I delete all characters after the first space in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833137/how-do-i-delete-all-characters-after-the-first-space-in-a-cell)

What I need is to apply this function from Row M2 up to the last entry at the end of column M. How can I do that if I have this code:

```
Sub TMP()

    Dim strCodeWithDesc As String
    Dim strCodeOnly As String
    strCodeWithDesc = Range("M2").Value
    strCodeOnly = Left(strCodeWithDesc, InStr(strCodeWithDesc, " ") - 1)
    Range("M2").Value = strCodeOnly

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The validity of this method is going to rely on how far it is into the data of each cell that the first space will be found. I've used an arbitrary maximum position of 99 characters which should cover most situations.

After using a [Range.Replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) to convert each space to 99 spaces, a [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) is performed with [xlFixedWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822876.aspx). Only the first 'column' is retained through assignment of the correct [xlColumnDataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241018%28v=office.12%29.aspx); TextToColumns auto-trims the excess spaces.

```
Sub keepFirstWord()
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, 13), .Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp))
            .Replace What:=Chr(32), Replacement:=Space(99), LookAt:=xlPart
            .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("M2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                           FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(99, 9))
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

If you start to perform this action on more that a few hundred cells, the advantages of [TextToColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) over looping through each cellnd individually parsing the value will quickly become apparent.

[image: keep_first_word_before]
                 <sup>Sample data before keepFirstWord()</sup>

[image: keep_first_word_after]
                 <sup>Sample data after keepFirstWord()</sup>

Comment: This did the trick! Very detailed explanation on how to come up with this code. Thank you for teaching!

Comment: As usual Jeeped's solution are never trivial and often out of the box . building on it I'd propose `.Range(.Cells(2, 13), .Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp)).Replace What:=Chr(32) & "*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart` which should shorten both code and execution

Comment: Wow that's great! This a little more faster I think. Thank you for all the contributions!

Comment: @user3598756 - I definitely have to spend more time with one-sided wildcards. That should have been an answer!

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
Sub Paolo()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Range("M2:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        r.Value = Split(r.Value, " ")(0)
    Next r
End Sub
```

*NOTE:*

If the cell contains no spaces, it is left unchanged.

Comment: This is how I would do it, too, using SPLIT

Comment: Fine solution. To which I'd add a warning and an improvement. The warning being that `Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row` returns the last non empty cell row of column "M" of the ActiveSheet, which may not always be the one your actually dealing with. The improvement being `r.Value = Split(.Value, " ", 2)` , thus not having to deal with array size limits (if any..)

Comment: just to say I missed an "r" before the 2nd `.Value`

Answer (score 2):

Try thise code below:

Sub TMP()

```
Dim strCodeWithDesc As String
Dim strCodeOnly As String
Dim R as range
For Each R in Range(Range("M2"), Range("XFD2").end(xltoleft))
   strCodeWithDesc = R.Value
   strCodeOnly = Left(strCodeWithDesc, InStr(1,strCodeWithDesc, " ",vbTextCompare) - 1)
   R.Value = strCodeOnly
Next R
```

End Sub

If you're using Excel 2003 or earlier version, use VI2 instead of XFD2

Comment: I have an error. It says "Runtime Error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument". The below line has an error after debugging: `strCodeOnly = Left(strCodeWithDesc, InStr(strCodeWithDesc, " ") - 1)`

Comment: O, you need to correct the instr piece to this: InStr(1,strCodeWithDesc, " ",vbTextCompare)

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are working across row 2 and the OP wanted to work down column M. Additionally, there is no safety valve for cell values that do not contain a space. The former can be quickly rectified by flipping the orientation of the range selection; the latter by always appending each strCodeWithDesc with a space to make sure that each has at least one; e.g. `strCodeWithDesc = R.Value & Chr(32)`

Comment: Triple true Jeeped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

see below

besides TMP is reduced

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CodeAndDesc") '<== set it as per your needs

With ws
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Call TMP(.Cells(i, 13))
    Next i
End With

End Sub


Sub TMP(rng As Range)
With rng
    .Value = Left(.Value, InStr(.Value, " ") - 1)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The above code just copy the value of the above cell and not deleting all the characters after the first space.

Comment: the above code just does on cells of column "M" from row 2 to last non empty row what your TMP() sub did on M2 cell only. Which is what I got from your question. Either I didn't got it right or you didn't test it

Comment: I've tested this also and it copied the cell above one by one. Thank you though for the contribution.

Comment: Please help me understand. It's quite straightforward to see that code doesn't copy anything while acts on every cell of column "M" (index 13) from row 2 to its last non empty one and treats its content as per your original TMP() sub, i.e. leaving only the text part before the first occurrence of a "space". Actually it'd throw an error if some cell hadn't any "space" in it. So the only possibility that a test would run leaving all cells as they are (which you may see as "copying" them) is they don't have "spaces" and the `Left(...)` statement is surrounded by some `On Error Resume Next` one