# Deleting text after first space

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete the text after first space in a cell in column C using the code below. For some reason I always get Runtime error 1004.

```
Sub keepFirstWord()
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range(.Cells(0, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .Replace What:=Chr(32), Replacement:=Space(99), LookAt:=xlPart
        .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                       FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(99, 9))
    End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: well you have mention `.Cells(0,1)` you are defining row as 0, so replace as `.cells(1,1)` also for additional info refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969634/delete-all-characters-after-the-first-space-in-a-cell-all-through-out-the-column)

Comment: Cells(0,1) doesn't exist, replace it with Cells(1,1) .. The first index in Cells is 1 not 0 ..